# Can you make Contacts show the Twitter username (instead of the person's real name) when it autopopulates data from Twitter?

Tags: macos, contacts, twitter

I had Contacts integrate data from my Twitter account. It worked, but when I look at someone's Twitter name in Contacts, it shows their *real* name, not their Twitter handle.

[image: My Contacts entry]

Above you can see my original, manually-typed Twitter name, followed by my Facebook name, followed by Mountain Lion's auto-populated Twitter field. It doesn't do me much good to see my friends' real names again; I want to see their handles.

I should note that when I right click on "Twitter" next to an autopopulated field and choose "Tweet", it works correctly; it's actually saving the Twitter handle in there. It's just not displaying it.

Is there a way, perhaps a `defaults write` command or something, to make Contacts show the Twitter handle?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't have this problem when importing Twitter details into my Contacts; the Twitter field shows their handle, as expected. Could there be a setting in OS X's Twitter integration to use full names rather than handles?

Comment: I'm seeing Twitter handles too. Did you perhaps use another contact manager that imported the names before looking in Contacts? I had used Cobook at some point, but it didn't import real names either.